# Loop through Excel worksheets and save text into a TXT file with C#

Tags: c#, worksheet, excel, export-to-text

I have most of the problem solved. I can loop through the worksheets, I can create the text file and write to it. The only problem I'm having is actually extracting the text or values from every sheet. Below is the code I have, but it only throws an object per worksheet and writes those words into my text file instead of the actual values.

```
System.Object[,]
System.Object[,]
```

What else am I missing?
I should point out I'm a beginner programmer.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("ExtractedText.txt"))
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook thisWkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(thisFile);

    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in thisWkBook.Worksheets)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(sheet.UsedRange.Value);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, not tested. See http://dontbreakthebuild.com/2011/01/30/excel-and-c-interop-with-net-4-how-to-read-data-from-excel/

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("ExtractedText.txt"))
{
    var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    var workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(thisFile);

    foreach (var sheet in workBook.Worksheets)
    {
      foreach (var row in sheet.UsedRange.Rows)
      {
        foreach (var cell in row.Columns)
        {
          sw.Write(cell.Value + " ");
        } 
        sw.WriteLine();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! So I needed to loop through the rows and columns as well! Gotcha. I'm testing this right away, thanks!

Comment: The `.Value2` part didn't work. But starting from your suggestion, I found that you can loop through the cells with 'foreach' statements as follows:      `foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in thisWkBook.Worksheets)
     {
  foreach (Excel.Range thisRow in sheet.UsedRange.Rows)
  {
      foreach (Excel.Range thisCell in thisRow.Columns)
      {
   sw.Write(thisCell.Value + " ");
      }
      sw.WriteLine();
  }` Would you like to update your answer so I can select it as the final answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the data fron the sheet, for example:

```
sw.WriteLine(sheet.Range["C5"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: This points me to the right direction (it's actually `Range["C5"]`, with brackets). Thanks!